# "\n" in php is not moving down a line in my file

Tags: php, post, handle

I'm writing a small php script to save form data to a file and everything is working fine, except \n isn't moving down a line in the file. It's printing all data on the same line.

```
<?php

$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$handle = fopen('details.txt','a');
fwrite($handle, $firstname ."\n");
fwrite($handle, $email);
?>
<br>
 Your email address is: <?php
 echo $_POST["email"];
?>
```

Comment: What operating system are you viewing the file on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Must be cross-platform line break issue. Your system might be expecting \r\n

Use **[PHP_EOL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)**

> The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. Available since PHP 5.0.2

This makes your new line cross platform. You don't have to worry about \n or \r\n anymore.

```
fwrite($handle, $firstname .PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: Thank you sir/madam, that's done the trick. I'll accept the answer in... 11 minutes.